# Create version of report with local links to referenced articles

Tags: hyperref, citing, external-files, draft

I have the following set-up in mind, and I hope someone could help me achieve this:

I cite entries from my `.bib` file. I use the `hyperref` package ([manual](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/teTeX/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf)) with the `pagebackref` option set to `true`, so when I run pdfLaTeX all my references point to the corresponding bibliography option and I can jump back to my reference.

During report writing this behaviour is not useful for me. I would rather have it such that a reference click would open the PDF file of the clicked article. 
So when I have a BibTex entry with label `{mylittlepony}`, I cite this with

```
Everybody loves chocolate \cite{mylittlepony}.
```

In the PDF file it says:

> Everybody loves chocolate [1].

Now if I click the [1] a file called `mylittlepony.pdf` should open from a pre-defined folder.

This behaviour should only occur during report writing. When I want to generate the document for other people the original `hyperref` behaviour should occur, so an additional option should be set for the `hyperref` package. This is a hard restriction.

I want this to work with TexWorks' (Windows) integrated PDF-viewer as I like the syncTex functionality. This is not a hard restriction. If there are other ways of keeping a simple editor, syncTex and the custom behaviour described above I would go for that.

I tried using the `\href` function to reference to local files, but this does not work in the integrated PDF-viewer, only in Acrobat Reader X.

Comment: Should `\cite{something}` always link to `something.pdf`?

Comment: My skill level is not sufficient to evaluate this idea.  Consider the redefinition of \cite after the loading of the hyperref package.  This new definition would reference the bibtex database to get the local file location of the pdf file (stored in a 'new' field name.)  This version of cite would use hyperref to put the hyperlink in place in the text.   Now when you want the original behavior you just comment out the \input statement which loaded the new definition of \cite (stored in a file).

Comment: @Caramdir: `\cite{something}` should only point to `something.pdf` if I am compiling the document during report writing as a draft version. If I compile the document for presentation it should just have the normal `\cite` behaviour

Comment: @R.Schumacher ; I understand your idea, but I see two problems. One - I have never redefined a LaTeX command. Two - as mentioned in the question I want it to work with TeXWorks integrated pdf viewer. If I use `hyperref` to establish the local file link I can only use that link in Acrobat Reader X. Thank you though for thinking with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifdraft{\let\obibcite=\bibcite}{}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\ifdraft{
  \let\bibcite=\obibcite
  \def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
  {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
  \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
  \hyper@linkurl{% NEW
  \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
  \G@refundefinedtrue
  \@latex@warning
  {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
  {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}%
  {\@citeb.pdf}% NEW
  }}{#1}}
}{}
\makeatother
```

It uses the [`ifdraft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft) package to determine whether the document is in draft mode. If so, the original definition of the `\bibcite` macro is saved, then [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is loaded (with the `final` option, otherwise no links would be generated at all). Now, we restore the `hyperref`-free version of `\bibcite` to remove the default link to the bibliography which is normally produced. Instead, we patch the internal LaTeX command `\@citex` to generate a hyperlink to the corresponding PDF file - so `\cite{mylittepony}` links to `mylittlepony.pdf` now.

#### Example code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifdraft{\let\obibcite=\bibcite}{}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\ifdraft{
  \let\bibcite=\obibcite
  \def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
  {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
  \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
  \hyper@linkurl{% NEW
  \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
  \G@refundefinedtrue
  \@latex@warning
  {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
  {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}%
  {\@citeb.pdf}% NEW
  }}{#1}}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Everybody loves chocolate \cite{mylittlepony}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{mylittlepony}
My bibliography entry.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

(The environment `thebibliography` is solely for making a self-contained example, you can replace it with your own `\bibliography{...}` without harm.)

This code is tested with TeXworks 0.4.3 on Windows 7, where it opens `mylittlepony.pdf` with the default PDF viewer. Note that it may not work with other versions of TeXworks or different operating systems: Unfortunately, the internal viewer has a very limited support for hyperlinks - direct file links are apparently not working, so this solution creates an URL link instead, which works for TeXworks, may break with other viewers on the other hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. However it's not entirely clear to me how I can define where the .pdf files reside. I am also used to using a .bib file for my references by calling `\bibliography` instead of a list of `\bibitem` in the main file. Does this change the code?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, it works fine with `\bibliography` as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: By changing the line `{\@citeb.pdf}` into ` {/refs/\@citeb.pdf}` I can now put my pdf files in the root/refs directory. This makes this code perfect.